# Can this sum be simplified: $ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} { n -1 \choose k } (-2)^{k} (2n - k)! $?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can this expression be further simplified : $ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} { n -1 \choose k } (-2)^{k} (2n - k)! $? This is the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the formal power series expansion of $(1-2x)^{n-1} \times \sum_{ k \geq 0} k! x^k$.

Motivation: I came across this when trying to solve a problem using inclusion-exclusion principle, I am not mentioning the original problem because I am interested in this sum as an independent problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the OEIS?

Comment: @robin: what is OEIS

Comment: @robin: yes. No luck : http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html?q=2,12,336,17760

Comment: Did you try WolframAlpha? It gives a solution in terms of the "Kummer confluent hypergeometric function", which may or may not be any better.

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks for suggesting wolfram alpha, I will take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a confluent hypergeometric function $\rm\ (2n)! \phantom{f}_1 F_1(1-n;\: -2\:n;\: -2)\ $, which can be expressed in closed form in terms of modified Bessel functions of the first kind, namely

$$\begin{split}(-1)^n &2^{\frac12-n}e^{-1-i\pi n}(n+1)\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma(2n)I_{\frac12(-2n-1)}(1)-\\&(-1)^n 2^{\frac12-n}e^{-1-i\pi n}\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma(2n)I_{\frac12(1-2n)}(1)\end{split}$$

It may well have a simpler closed form, since the various hypergeometric simplifiers in CAS are not always optimal (above is via *Mathematica*). It is not known by the OEIS Superseeker, so you may wish to submit it there.

Answer (score 8):

As a way of restating Bill's answer, what you have can in fact be expressed in terms of the so-called [(generalized) Bessel polynomial](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.34.E1):

$$y_n(x;a)=(n+a-1)_n \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n {}_1 F_1 \left(-n;-2n-a+2;\frac{2}{x}\right)$$

(the Kummer hypergeometric series degenerates to a polynomial here because both the numerator and denominator parameters are negative integers)

Your original expression, then, in terms of the (generalized) Bessel polynomial, is

$$(-2)^{n-1}(n+1)!y_{n-1}(-1;4)$$

The references in the DLMF can point you to papers where the (generalized) Bessel polynomials have been studied; for an elementary treatment, see Chihara's [*An Introduction to Orthogonal Polynomials*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0677041500).